# parse XML nodes with the name "object" in XDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

my problem is as follows: 
I want to parse a xml-file created with Tiled Map Editor where I inserted one objectlayer (for collision objects). But unfortunately, Tiled named the node in the xml-file "objectgroup" and its descendants "object"

```
<objectgroup name="solidObjects" width="100" height="100">
 <object gid="265" x="16" y="35"/>
 <object gid="265" x="66" y="36"/>
</objectgroup>
```

I am trying to do something like

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("pathtoFile\sourcefile.xml");
List<Rectangle> objectList = new List<Rectangle>();

foreach (var object in doc.Element("objectgroup").Descendants("object"))
{ objectList.Add(objectRectangle); }
```

But since "object" is a protected word in c#, it doesn't work. 
Any tips how to handle this problem the easiest way?

Comment: Why not just choosing another variable name?

Comment: yeah - just call it `obj` or something

Comment: Oh, I thought the variable has to have the same name as the node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely, definitely *have* to use `object` as your variable name (which is not recommended), then you can prefix it with an `@` sign:

```
foreach (var @object in doc.Element("objectgroup").Descendants("object")) {
    objectList.Add(@object);
}
```

The `@` sign prefix allows identifiers in your code to use reserved words as their names.